# java regex: extract text after delimeter?

Tags: java, regex

i am new to regular expressions in Java. I like to extract a string by using regular expressions.

This is my String: "Hello,World"

I like to extract the text after ",". The result would be "World". I tried this:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(.+?)"); 
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello,World"); 
matcher.find();
```

But what would be the next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Regex for this. You can simply split on comma and get the 2nd element from the array: -

```
System.out.println("Hello,World".split(",")[1]);
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
World
```

---

**But if you want to use `Regex`**, you need to remove `?` from your Regex.

`?` after `+` is used for `Reluctant` matching. It will **only match `W`** and stop there. 
You don't need that here. You need to match until it can match.

So use **`greedy`** matching instead.

**Here's the code with modified Regex: -**

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(.+)"); 
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello,World"); 

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
World
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending what you have, you need to remove the **?** sign from your pattern to use the greedy matching and then process the matched group:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(.+)");       // removed your '?'
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello,World"); 

while (matcher.find()) {

    String result = matcher.group(1);

    // work with result

}
```

Other answers suggest different approaches to your problem and might offer better solution for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println( "Hello,World".replaceAll(".*,(.*)","$1") ); // output is "World"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a reluctant expression and will only select a single character `W`, whereas you can use a *greedy* one and print your matched group content:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",(.+)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello,World");
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
World
```

See [Regex Pattern doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)